# Typing into a form's input causes a button cannot be clicked for several seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following scenario:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      newWord: ['',
        [
          Validators.minLength(1),
          Validators.maxLength(15)
        ]
      ]
    });
    this.words = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }

  form!: FormGroup;
  words!: string[];

  addWord(): void {
    if (this.form.controls['newWord'].valid) {
      this.words.push(this.form.controls['newWord'].value);
      this.form.controls['newWord'].reset();
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="words">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let word of words">
                {{word}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="new-word">
        <input formControlName="newWord" type="text">
        <button (click)="addWord()" type="button">Add New Word</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

There is a problem with this code. When I push the `button` just after typing a new word into the `input` I find this button frozen (that is, its click callback, `addWord()`, can't be called) for somewhat three seconds after the typing. This does not take place if I just push  the button several times without any preceding typing so seemingly the problem comes from a slow input model processing.

Is this behavior expectable for Angular reactive forms or do I something wrong and there is a way to get rid of such a long delay?

Comment: In my experience with reactive forms they are pretty performant, so most likely there is a logic issue somewhere. But your code looks pretty sensible to me. Any chance you would be able to recreate the issue in a StackBlitz so we can investigate further?

Comment: it's looks like work :(. See your forked code in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmsl7y?file=src%2Fmain.ts). NOTE: if at first you want an empty array in words, declare words as `words: string[]=[]`

Comment: NOTE: you can use a simple FormControl instead a FormGroup with a formControl (in the stackblitz I make the same with a formControl)

Comment: @nate-kumar It's seems that the problem was in my touchpad, wow. Angular does its best. Thank you for you help, I'll try to close this question.

Comment: @Eliseo It's seems that the problem was in my touchpad, wow. Angular does its best. Thank you for you help, I'll try to close this question.